# How to correctly modelize FAQ Questions and Answers?

Tags: java, database, database-design, treeview

I'm actually working on an FAQ system where questions can be answers to other questions.
The principle that i must respect is that a well-defined set of questions is shown to the user at start (the most general questions). Then, further we go into the "tree", more specific will the questions / answers be. And at the end of the tree (leaf) there will be the most suitable answer for the user.

I've thinking of using a tree. The fact is I've only studied it last year in my Computer Science Degree so I'm like a beginner in the field (in practice mostly).

The questions and answers will be stored in a database and show progressively to the user regarding chosen "path" through the FAQ system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if a question can be an answer to another question, then you might want to take a very general approach and say that any one piece of text can be a child (branch) of any other piece of text.  For example:

- Statement answers a question
- Question answers a question
- Statement comments on a question
- Statement comments on another statement

This being the case a simple table with a self-referencing relationship (parent item foreign key) will probably be both simple and effective for you.